# Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp, fatal-error

Line 95 at index.php taht shows the error:

```
if (!include 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php') {
```

I get the error `Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your \cake core directory and your \vendors root directory.`

Comment: What version of Cake are you using?

Comment: Maybe just run composer update on root of your project solves this issue